# AEM Gradle OSGI Plugins

Tags: gradle, aem, gradle-plugin

Hi Im looking to build my AEM Cq5 project with Gradle, I have looked at the TWCable plugins, but some of the documentation around it is poor and lacking functionality like embedding dependencies in my osgi containers.

Is there any recommendations anyone could make for building osgi (bnd tool) aem jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone knows of an existing plugin that does everything you're asking, that would be great to know. (I'm the primary author of those TWC plugins.)

Otherwise you may want to file an issue/question against the appropriate project on GitHub: https://github.com/TWCable/

Comment: Jim do you have any example build.gradle file that is complete? I added a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234132/how-can-we-create-a-build-gradle-equivalent-file-for-pom-xml-to-build-and-deploy

Answer (score 1):

I am recommending to use our brand new plugin "Gradle AEM Plugin".

https://github.com/Cognifide/gradle-aem-plugin

it has many fancy features, like automated creation of local instances from remote JAR locations (SMB, HTTP(S), SFTP) with pre-installed dependent packages, application build - all in parallel to speed up developer setup process to maximum.