# How can we create a build.gradle equivalent file for pom.xml to build and deploy AEM code?

Tags: maven, gradle, osgi, aem

I'm trying to create a **build.gradle** file like the complete pom.xml for [AEM Maven Archetype](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-project-archetype) or [Lazybones Template](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/lazybones-aem-templates) to build and deploy the code to AEM.

- I tried to use [TWCCable's CQ Plugin](https://github.com/TWCable/gradle-plugin-cq-bundle) but wasn't sure how to use
  it.
- Also tried to run **gradle init** on the main pom.xml but obviously it was incomplete (below) and i think i'll have to add all dependencies manually.

  ```
  allprojects  {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    group = 'com.project2'
    version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
  }
  subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6

    repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      maven { url "https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public" }
      maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
    }
    configurations.all {
    }
  }
  ```

Is there any example file that i could use? My goal is to use **gradle build** instead of using **mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage** , not sure if i can even do it?

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

As an author of new tool I'd like to encourage AEM devs for using:

https://github.com/Cognifide/gradle-aem-plugin (brand new, feature rich Gradle plugin)
https://github.com/Cognifide/gradle-aem-example (example project, just clone and test)

Enjoy!